# No puedo ver localmente mi aplicación Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C ¿Como lo soluciono?

Tags: php, localhost

Tengo esta configuración
php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if (!$con)
{
    die("No se puede conectar: ". mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("local", $con) or die (mysql_error());
```

?>
Me sale este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\conecta.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(5): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\persistencia\conecta.php on line 6

Comment: Las funciones mysql estan eliminadas desde la versión 7.0 de PHP.  Seguramente estás usando una versión igual o superior de PHP y por eso no la encuentra. Mira de cambiar todo lo que sea `mysql_` por `mysqli_` y a ver si con eso es suficiente para saltarte ese error.

Comment: Creo que tienes puesto `mysqli__connect` en lugar de `mysqli_connect`

Comment: @loraine, necesitas prestar un poco mas de atención, estas escribiendo el nombre de las funciones mal, no es `mysqli__select_db` es `mysqli_select_db`. Si tenes algún otro problema con los métodos de `MySQLi` te recomiendo [leer la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).